# Angular 12 Universal on Google App Engine error: ./my-app/server/main.js: Syntax error: "(" unexpected

Tags: angular, google-app-engine, universal, app.yaml, server-error

I have an Angular 12 app that I converted to Universal.
After shmoozing it a bit it works locally as expected.
I deployed to Google AppEngine but get *'500 Error: Server Error'*.
Looking at the logs I see the error:
`./my-app/server/main.js: Syntax error: "(" unexpected.`

My app.yaml is simply:
`runtime: nodejs14`
`entrypoint: ./my-app/server/main.js`

I tried building with and without `--prod` but I still get the same error.
Any help will be appreciated...
**Update**:
When removing the *entrypoint* from *app.yaml* I get the error:

```
Error: Cannot find module '/workspace/server.js' at 
Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:889:15) at 
Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js
```

Here is the scripts section of *package.json*:

```
{  
  "name": "my-app",  
  "version": "1.0.0",  
  "scripts":   
{  
    "ng": "ng",  
    "start": "ng serve",  
    "build": "ng build",  
    "prod-build": "ng build --prod",  
    "test": "ng test",  
    "lint": "ng lint",  
    "e2e": "ng e2e",  
    "dev:ssr": "ng run my-app:serve-ssr",  
    "serve:ssr": "node dist/my-app/server/main.js",  
    "build:ssr": "ng build && ng run my-app:server",  
    "prerender": "ng run my-app:prerender"  
  },  
...
```

Comment: As per this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/config/appref#entrypoint) Entrypoint Overrides the default startup behavior by executing the entrypoint command when your app starts. For your app to receive HTTP requests, the entrypoint element should contain a command which starts a web server that listens on port 8080. If you do not specify an entrypoint, App Engine uses the start script specified in your package.json file.

Comment: When I remove the entry point I get the error: `Error: Cannot find module '/workspace/server.js' at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:889:15) at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js`

I added the scripts section of package.json

Comment: Hi, can you please provide your folder structure? And I did try to reproduce the issue, I am receiving 500 server error when I am providing entrypoint, but it works fine when I remove it.

Comment: It didn't work for me when I removed the entrypoint and just had the 'start' script in package.json. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally solved it (following a discussion with good folk at Angular.io):
It works as advertised if I change app.yaml to the following:

```
runtime: nodejs14
entrypoint: node dist/my-app/server/main.js
```

The folder structure is exactly what you get from the universal code generator:
{your project}
  dist
    my-app
      browser
        ... Regular Angular  site files ...
      server
        main.js
        ...

In AppEngine the structure you want to upload and sync to your project is:
{your project}
  app.yaml
  dist